# Chebyshev Nodes Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, chebyshev-polynomials

I am a bit confused as to what role the Chebyshev nodes play in the optimization of Langrage Polynomial Interpolation.

Reading online for what I understand that the Chebyshev nodes gives us the minimum error, I may be doing something wrong but take a look at the following example:

Approximating $f(x) = x^3$ with a linear Langrage interpolating polynomial with the Chebyshev nodes gives us that $P_1(x) = 0.5x$, this gives us a maximum error of 0.5 on the interval $[-1,1]$.

but if I had chosen the nodes $x_1=\sqrt0.6 , x_2= -\sqrt0.6$, then my interpolating polynomial becomes $P_1^*(x) = 0.6x$ giving us a maximum error of 0.4 on the same interval.

I know I must be misunderstanding something. What gives?

Comment: It doesn't give the minimum maximum error, it gives a rough approximation for it. Usually trying to find the exact best is difficult because $\min_P\max_x|f(x)-P(x)|$ is an intractable problem, which is why Chebyshev nodes are used.

Comment: Chebychev nodes only gives an upper bound for the maximum error (that depends on the degree of the interpolating polynomial), it does not guarantee anything about the minimum of the maximum error.